# C++ thread synchronization by mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

I am new to parallel programming, and I am trying to decompose an iterative matrix computation on multiple threads: each iteration consists of two sequential jobs A and B; it needs to wait for all the threads to finish job A before job B is launched.

I used a mutex lock to sync between all threads, and the following is an example script.  The output changes randomly when I run the script for multiple times, so I am guessing I messed up with the thread synchronization.  Could anybody please advise?  Thanks!

```
static std::mutex mutex_A, mutex_B;
static std::condition_variable cv_A, cv_B;

int main()
{
    int Nthread=2;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(Nthread);
    for(int thread_id=0; thread_id < Nthread; thread_id++)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([](){
            for(int iter=0; iter<3000; iter++){
                
                // launch job A

                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_A{mutex_A};
                cv_A.wait(lock_A, [=](){return true;});
                cv_A.notify_all();

                // launch job B

                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_B{mutex_B};
                cv_B.wait(lock_B, [=](){return true;});
                cv_B.notify_all();
            }
        })
    }
    for(auto &thread: threads)
        thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps an atomic counter would be better in this case? Initialize it to `Nthread`, then each thread decrements it and waits until it becomes zero before continuing.

Comment: Something to think about: Assume any arbitrary thread finishes its job A – then next thing it does is waiting – if all threads do so – which of these is going to wake up all threads, including itself? So the point is: you are relying on *spurious wakeups* to get the matter right at all (if none occurs all your threads remain waiting, i.e. blocked). And these might occur any time, not considering all threads having finished so far...

Comment: I'd join @Someprogrammerdude 's counter approach, you can rely on [operator--](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith), it provides you with the thread safety you need and still gives you correct value, so something like: `if(--counter != 0) { /* wait */ } else { /* notify all others waiting */ }` and within the lambda you need to check, too, if the counter actually reached 0 (`[&counter]() { return counter.load() == 0; }`) to prevent continuing on spurious wakeups.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and the detailed explanation.  Now I have a better idea on what happened under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are notifying the condition variables without releasing the lock -- causing the threads to block indefinitely

```
static std::mutex mutex_A, mutex_B;
static std::condition_variable cv_A, cv_B;

int main()
{
    int Nthread = 2;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::atomic<int> count_A(0);
    std::atomic<int> count_B(0);

    for(int thread_id = 0; thread_id < Nthread; thread_id++)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&](){
            for(int iter = 0; iter < 3000; iter++){

                // launch job A
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_A(mutex_A);
                    // Wait for all threads to finish job A
                    if(++count_A == Nthread) {
                        count_A.store(0);
                        cv_A.notify_all();
                    } else {
                        cv_A.wait(lock_A, [&](){return count_A == 0;});
                    }
                }

                // launch job B
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_B(mutex_B);
                    // Wait for all threads to finish job B
                    if(++count_B == Nthread) {
                        count_B.store(0);
                        cv_B.notify_all();
                    } else {
                        cv_B.wait(lock_B, [&](){return count_B == 0;});
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    for(auto &thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

- used 2 atomic counters (count_A + count_B) -- keeps track of how many threads have finished job A|B respectively

thread finishes job A|B -- increments corresponding counter + checks if it's the last thread to finish(last thread -- resets counter + notifies all threads waiting on the corresponding condition variable -- else -- waits on the condition variable until all threads have finished)

- lambda function -- checks condition for waiting on the condition variable(count_A == 0 | count_B == 0 ensures that all threads have finished corresponding job)

hopefully, after these changes output should be deterministic

Comment: Just that I'd rather count down from `Nthread` to 0, this avoids having store 0 back again, i.e. `count_A(Nthread); /*...*/ if(--count_A != 0) { cv_a.wait(); } else { cv_a.notify_all(); }`

Comment: I see no `operator==` being defined for [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), so should be `count_A.load() == 0`.

Comment: @Aconcagua C++14 allows me to use operator== with the atomic so I guess it is overloaded.

Comment: @user19754998 Hm... At least it *seems* not to be documented at cppreference – and implicit conversion to the underlying type doesn't seem to exist either (non-explicit constructor doesn't help out here...). Is this one of the rare cases of cppreference trailing the standard?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try using a mutex to coordinate the activity of different threads. It'll just drive you crazy. The only purpose for which you should ever use a mutex is to prevent different threads from accessing the same shared data at the same time.

If you are using C++20, then you can use a [`std::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier) to achieve your goal.

```C++
int main()
{
    int Nthread=2;
    std::barrier barrier(Nthread);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(Nthread);
    for(int thread_id=0; thread_id < Nthread; thread_id++)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([](){
            for(int iter=0; iter<3000; iter++){
                
                jobA();
                barrier.arrive_and_wait();

                // No thread can get _past_ the barrier until Nthread 
                // threads have arrived _at_ the barrier (I.E., not until
                // all of the threads have completed jobA()).
                //
                // Once Nthread threads have arrived, the threads all are 
                // released to go on to perform jobB(), and the barrier is
                // automatically reset, ready to be used again.

                jobB();
                barrier.arrive_and_wait();

                // No thread can get past the barrier until all threads have
                // completed jobB();
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

If you must use a C++ version older than C++20, then your next best bet would be to use [`boost::barrier`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/barrier.html). If you can't do that, then maybe find an open-source implementation of `barrier`, and incorporate the source into your program.